# Subsequence Avoiding Sequences

Tags: combinatorics

An answer of mine disagrees with an answer in a math book I'm reading, and so I wanted to sanity check it to see if there's something obvious I'm missing.

The book Foundations of Mathematical Analysis by Paul J. Sally Jr. defines a subsequence avoiding sequence to be a sequence $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ such that, for any indices $0 < i < j \leq n/2,$ $$x_i, x_{i+1}, ..., x_{2i}$$ is not a subsequence of $$x_j, x_{j+1}, ..., x_{2j}.$$

He defines $n(k)$ to be the length of the longest subsequence avoiding sequence whose terms lie in $\{1, 2, ..., k\}.$ He states that $n(1) = 3, n(2) = 11.$

I agree that $n(1) = 3,$ but I believe that the sequence

$$1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2$$

is subsequence avoiding and of length 12, contradicting his claim that $n(2) = 11.$

Now, the subsequences of that sequence of the form $$x_i, ..., x_{2i}$$ for $i\leq n/2$ are, respectively,
$$1, 1,$$
$$1,2,2,$$
$$2,2,2,2,$$
$$2,2,2,1,2,$$
$$2,2,1,2,1,2$$
$$2,1,2,1,2,1,2.$$

It's clear that none of them contain each other. So, have I made some silly mistake? Or was there a typo in the entry $n(2) = 11$?

Comment: What is the definition of subsequence in this context?  Normally, in subsequences you can skip elements, so that $2,2,2,2$ is a subsequence of $2,2,2,1,2.$  If you can't skip elements, I think this is usually called a sublist (at least in computer science.)  If one can't skip elements, your example looks right.  If one can skip elements, I'd like to see the example with $11$ terms.

Comment: Ah! I think you may be right--you can skip elements. The book does not provide an example with 11 terms, although now I know what to start looking for!

Comment: @saulspatz - Here's the example with $11$ terms: $1222111111x.$  There are only $5$ candidates: $12, 222, 2211, 21111, 111111$ and none is a subseq of another.  The last letter $x$ is not part of any candidate and can be either symbol.  (This also means all $n(k)$ must be odd, as the last symbol is not part of any candidate if total length is odd.)

Comment: @antkam I think you should make that an answer, since the OP didn't have an example.

Answer (score 1):

Using the definition from @saulspatz that a subsequence allows skipping terms, here is an example with $11$ terms:  $1222111111x$

There are only $5$ candidates: $12, 222, 2211, 21111, 111111$ and none is a subsequence of another.  The last letter $x$ is not part of any candidate and can be either symbol.  (This also means all $n(k)$ must be odd, as the last symbol is not part of any candidate if the total length is odd.)

BTW I found this by "manual backtracking" :) - it turns out starting with $11$ limits you to a shorter length.  And starting with $12$ means once another $1$ appears the rest must be all $1$s (except for the last $x$) so it's just a matter of how many $2$s you can fit in before the reappearance of $1$.